# DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again

Tags: 16.04, networking, openvpn

I use OpenVPN to connect to workplace's network. When I connect, the connection is good and then it suddenly drops with the following trace. With this the internet connection from my router also drops both wifi and ethernet. I have to restart my router to get back the internet connection.

```
Please enter your username and password.
GROUP: [xxxxx]:xxxxx
POST https://xxxx.com/
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
POST https://xxxxxx.com/
Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CSTP connected. DPD 30, Keepalive 20
Connected tun0 as 192.168.20.101, using SSL
DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
CSTP Dead Peer Detection detected dead peer!
Failed to reconnect to host xxxxxx.com
sleep 10s, remaining timeout 300s
Failed to reconnect to host xxxxxx.com
sleep 20s, remaining timeout 290s
Failed to reconnect to host xxxxxx.com
sleep 30s, remaining timeout 270s
Failed to reconnect to host xxxxxx.com
sleep 40s, remaining timeout 240s
^CSocket connect cancelled
Failed to reconnect to host xxxxxx.com
sleep 50s, remaining timeout 200s
Reconnect failed
```

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: FWIW, I have the same problem, using openconnect, but just restarting openconnect usually works, and not the router.